# jquery scrolling won't scroll from exact location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following jquery to make my links scroll to the next div.  However, I've run into a problem.  From the top of the page the script works fine.  As soon as I click a link from another div (another link further down the page) the script only scrolls so far either up or down but not to the next specified div.  How can I make the script scroll fully from the current location of where the link is located?

```
$(function() {
$('#nav a').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this);

    $('html, body, #container, .main').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the correct spot...

this should do the trick... Set the anchor point first.

```
$(function() {
$('#nav a').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this).attr('href');

    $('html, body, #container, .main').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor).offset().top
    }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

Comment: Ugh!  This didn't work either.  It is still doing the same thing.  The page scrolls randomly up or down but not to the next specified div. Thank you though for helping me out... I'm a bit of a beginner.

Comment: Okay what happens if you do a console.log($($anchor).offset().top); do you get a number?

Comment: sorry... again beginner... how/where do I go about doing that?

Comment: right after your $anchor varaiable... the post above with a fiddle is working and exactly what I am saying but with a working example... that's what you need to be doing... possibly you're not defining your div ID's?

Comment: would you mind writing out the whole code I would need to put in.  I know how to look at the console, but can't seem to place the code you gave me in the right spot..

Comment: @Jai already did - http://jsfiddle.net/egzHC/ that's everything you need. That works perfectly.

Comment: Ok I used your code and did a little tweaking.  I FIXED THE PROBLEM!  Many thanks my friend!

Answer (score 1):

You have a error here:

```
scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
     //------^^^^^^^---------------------------------this itself a selector
```

change to this and try with:

```
scrollTop: $anchor.attr('href').offset().top
```

or this one too:

```
 $('#nav a').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body, #container, .main').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor).offset().top
    }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
 });
```

#### [CHECKOUT IN FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/egzHC/)

Comment: just added another version you can try this one.

Comment: Sorry didn't work either... thanks for the effort I really appreciate it!  I'm hoping to fix this soon.

Comment: Both times were a no-go.  Sorry to say.

Comment: Just updated the answer and added a fiddle working quite well. Check that out.

Comment: thanks again but for some reason my original problem remains.  When I click a link, say from the next div to go even further, thats where my problems lies.  Then the script messes up and sends me to either the top of the page, or somewhere in between divs.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I've made you a JSFiddle, the js-code I rewrote to the code below, but you can have a have a look at the full thing here: http://jsfiddle.net/re7Xc/

```
$(function() {
     $('a.scrolltonext').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var parentblock = $(this).parent();
     var nextblock = parentblock.next();
     //nextblock.css('background-color','#00f');

         if(nextblock.size()>0) {
              $('html, body').stop().animate({
                   'scrollTop': nextblock.offset().top
              }, 800);
         }
     }); 
});
```

the catch in this script though is that I put the links in the div itself, so it's not in a #nav somewhere. So you'd have to **rewrite** that part if you put the links in your #nav!

I put an if-statement in there as well, because I thought it'd be better if you check if there is a next-div first, before scrolling there.

Hope it makes some sense, and let me know if it works for you!
cheers

Comment: Thank you for the help but I already fixed my problem!  I do have another question on my profile that needs a look at however!